# Parsing Nested JSON in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, parsing

```
{
  data: {
    report: {
      dns_records: {
        ns: {
          records: [
            {
              target: "ns2.google.com",
              ip: "216.239.34.10",
              country_code: "US",
              country_name: "United States of America",
              isp: "Google LLC"
            },
            {
              target: "ns1.google.com",
              ip: "216.239.32.10",
              country_code: "US",
              country_name: "United States of America",
              isp: "Google LLC"
            },
            {
              target: "ns4.google.com",
              ip: "216.239.38.10",
              country_code: "US",
              country_name: "United States of America",
              isp: "Google LLC"
            },
            {
              target: "ns3.google.com",
              ip: "216.239.36.10",
              country_code: "US",
              country_name: "United States of America",
              isp: "Google LLC"
            }
          ]
        },
        mx: {
          records: [
            {
              target: "alt1.aspmx.l.google.com",
              ip: "209.85.202.26",
              country_code: "US",
              country_name: "United States of America",
              isp: "Google LLC"
            },
            {
              target: "alt2.aspmx.l.google.com",
              ip: "64.233.184.26",
              country_code: "US",
              country_name: "United States of America",
              isp: "Google LLC"
            },
            {
              target: "aspmx.l.google.com",
              ip: "173.194.216.26",
              country_code: "US",
              country_name: "United States of America",
              isp: "Google LLC"
            },
            {
              target: "alt4.aspmx.l.google.com",
              ip: "142.251.9.26",
              country_code: "US",
              country_name: "United States of America",
              isp: "Google LLC"
            },
            {
              target: "alt3.aspmx.l.google.com",
              ip: "142.250.153.26",
              country_code: "NL",
              country_name: "Netherlands",
              isp: "Google LLC"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      domain_blacklist: {
        engines: [
          {
            name: "ThreatLog",
            reference: "https://www.threatlog.com/",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "OpenPhish",
            reference: "https://openphish.com/",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "PhishTank",
            reference: "https://www.phishtank.com/",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "Phishing.Database",
            reference: "https://github.com/mitchellkrogza/Phishing.Database",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "PhishStats",
            reference: "https://phishstats.info/",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "URLVir",
            reference: "https://www.urlvir.com/",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "URLhaus",
            reference: "https://urlhaus.abuse.ch/",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "RPiList Not Serious",
            reference: "https://github.com/RPiList/specials",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "AntiSocial Blacklist",
            reference: "https://theantisocialengineer.com/",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "PhishFeed",
            reference: "https://phishfeed.com/",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "NABP Not Recommended Sites",
            reference: "https://safe.pharmacy/buy-safely/",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "Spam404",
            reference: "https://www.spam404.com/",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "CRDF",
            reference: "https://threatcenter.crdf.fr/check.html",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "Artists Against 419",
            reference: "http://wiki.aa419.org/index.php/Main_Page",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "CERT Polska",
            reference: "https://www.cert.pl/",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "Scam.Directory",
            reference: "https://scam.directory/",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "PetScams",
            reference: "https://petscams.com/",
            detected: false
          },
          {
            name: "Suspicious Hosting IP",
            reference: "https://www.novirusthanks.org/",
            detected: false
          }
        ],
        detections: 0
      },
      file_type: {
        signature: "",
        extension: "",
        headers: "HTML"
      },
      geo_location: {
        countries: [
          "US",
          "NL"
        ]
      },
      html_forms: {
        number_of_total_forms: 1,
        number_of_total_input_fields: 8,
        two_text_inputs_in_a_form: false,
        credit_card_field_present: false,
        password_field_present: false,
        email_field_present: false
      },
      redirection: {
        found: false,
        external: false,
        url: null
      },
      response_headers: {
        code: 200,
        status: "HTTP/2 200",
        date: "Tue, 27 Jul 2021 20:32:40 GMT",
        expires: "-1",
        cache-control: "private, max-age=0",
        content-type: "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
        strict-transport-security: "max-age=31536000",
        p3p: "CP="ThisisnotaP3Ppolicy!Seeg.co/p3phelpformoreinfo."",
        server: "gws",
        x-xss-protection: "0",
        x-frame-options: "SAMEORIGIN",
        set-cookie: "1P_JAR=2021-07-27-20; expires=Thu, 26-Aug-2021 20:32:40 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure; SameSite=none NID=220=nWPEsD7iVK5Co2H5yUqIi4wCPAesnjuPJ4lsxOdtSH5utroyMfIpGpk2hcGOqmJ_ZVCTh9LnxT7_qFpPDrCw2WvYS6sHl8KNuCXm3an8LFzqVReWDxgGzUXdQZ6meK3AR6xpOfbbal8OUpACK8dQdEJWl3Jm5KjWLtlirdiNwIE; expires=Wed, 26-Jan-2022 20:32:40 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=none",
        accept-ranges: "none",
        vary: "Accept-Encoding"
      },
      risk_score: {
        result: 0
      },
      security_checks: {
        is_host_an_ipv4: false,
        is_suspicious_url_pattern: false,
        is_suspicious_file_extension: false,
        is_robots_noindex: false,
        is_suspended_page: false,
        is_most_abused_tld: false,
        is_uncommon_clickable_url: false,
        is_phishing_heuristic: false,
        is_possible_emotet: false,
        is_suspicious_content: false,
        is_empty_page_title: false,
        is_empty_page_content: false,
        is_domain_blacklisted: false,
        is_suspicious_domain: false,
        is_sinkholed_domain: false,
        is_defaced_heuristic: false,
        is_masked_file: false,
        is_risky_geo_location: false,
        is_china_country: false,
        is_nigeria_country: false,
        is_non_standard_port: false,
        is_email_address_on_url_query: false,
        is_directory_listing: false,
        is_exe_on_directory_listing: false,
        is_zip_on_directory_listing: false,
        is_php_on_directory_listing: false,
        is_doc_on_directory_listing: false,
        is_pdf_on_directory_listing: false,
        is_linux_elf_file: false,
        is_linux_elf_file_on_free_dynamic_dns: false,
        is_linux_elf_file_on_free_hosting: false,
        is_linux_elf_file_on_ipv4: false,
        is_masked_linux_elf_file: false,
        is_masked_windows_exe_file: false,
        is_ms_office_file: false,
        is_windows_exe_file_on_free_dynamic_dns: false,
        is_windows_exe_file_on_free_hosting: false,
        is_windows_exe_file_on_ipv4: false,
        is_windows_exe_file: false,
        is_external_redirect: false,
        is_credit_card_field: false,
        is_password_field: false,
        is_valid_https: true
      },
      server_details: {
        ip: "172.217.193.103",
        hostname: "",
        continent_code: "NA",
        continent_name: "North America",
        country_code: "US",
        country_name: "United States of America",
        region_name: "California",
        city_name: "Mountain View",
        latitude: 37.40599060058594,
        longitude: -122.0785140991211,
        isp: "Google LLC"
      },
      site_category: {
        is_torrent: false,
        is_vpn_provider: false,
        is_free_hosting: false,
        is_anonymizer: false,
        is_url_shortener: false,
        is_free_dynamic_dns: false
      },
      url_parts: {
        scheme: "https",
        host: "www.google.com",
        host_nowww: "google.com",
        port: null,
        path: "/",
        query: null
      },
      web_page: {
        title: "Google",
        description: "",
        keywords: ""
      }
    }
  },
  credits_remained: 1353.5,
  estimated_queries: "2,707",
  elapsed_time: "0.22",
  success: true
}
```

Hi all I am new to working with Kotlin Android and parsing JSON Basically I am getting the JSONString returned to my application using OKhttp but I am struggling to extract the risk score and security check objects from the returned JSON any help would be appreciated. i believe the JSON response is structured mainly in objects but I'm not sure its been a while since i worked with JSON

Comment: That's not even a valid json, could you post the real one?

Comment: I am not sure how to post it differently I put the JSON into code tags i have the URL of the Endpoint if that help thanks

Comment: Just copy what you get from your service and paste it here, but according to [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) that's not a valid json

Comment: it's not working for me sorry, thanks for the response

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS i formatted the json and updated the question. It will get approved after review from moderators.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS can you please update the actual response structure or a postman reference because it seems like you have added the headers also in the json object. I can see stars before the risk score `**risk_score:`. We have response headers in the json as key `response_headers`

Comment: the ** were added by me my mistake i tried to make the font bold just to make what i wanted standout the text box must have done that sorry

Comment: have you try a plugins or converter e.g: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass- to map your JSON to a `data class` or POJOs equivalent, therefore you can access your Object hopefully

Answer (score 0):

```
var basejsonObject = JSONObject(body)

            var datajsonObject = basejsonObject.getJSONObject("data")

            var reportjsonObject = datajsonObject.getJSONObject("report")

            var riskscorejsonObject = reportjsonObject.getJSONObject("risk_score")
```

I managed to access the object using the solution above breaking down into objects

Comment: You can move to a high-level library like Feign or Retrofit. In spite of these great features, OkHttp doesn't have a built-in encoder/decoder for JSON, XML, and other content types. However, we can implement these with the help of XML/JSON binding libraries, or we can use high-level libraries like Feign or Retrofit. Check this article for more insights. https://www.baeldung.com/okhttp-json-response

Comment: Ill Check it out thank you for the input @MohitAjwani